# IConfiguration object is null.

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to read connection strings from `appsettings.json` and I'm using:

```
services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
```

This line from startup throws null. I'm pretty new to core2.0. Can someone tell what I'm missing?

My startup:

```
public class Startup
{
    public static string ConnectionString { get; private set; }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
public class CreateController : Controller
{
    public IConfiguration _ConnectionString;
    public CreateController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _ConnectionString = configuration;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        Markets();
    }

    public string Markets()
    {
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString.GetSection("Data").GetSection("ConnectionString").Value))
        {
            return con.Database;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where was Configuration set? Also you should read the fundamentals documentation on Configuration and settings https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options

Comment: It is advised not to inject `IConfiguration` into your controllers.

Comment: Plus this appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to read connection strings from my appsettings.json

Comment: Can you include your `Program.cs` class in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling `services.AddSingleton(Configuration)` in `ConfigureServices`. It is already in the DI container by default.

You simply need to reference it within your `Controler`:

```
public class CreateController : Controller
{

    public IConfiguration _configuration;
    public CreateController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        Markets();
    }

    public string Markets()
    {
        var connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStringName");
        using( SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString) )
        {
            return con.Database;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I've noticed your `Startup` is missing a constructor. In ASP.NET Core 2, when it calls startup (based on a typical `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>()` inside a vanilla `Program.BuildWebHost`) will automatically pass the configuration into the Startup constructor:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This configuration is automatic, if WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args) is used in Program.cs
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
```

Just adding that will solve your IConfiguration is null issue.

Now, you *should not have to* add that Configuration into DI because with the defaults it should already be in there and you can add it as-is to your controller constructor. However, there's no harm in doing so.

Lastly, to join the chorus, using IConfiguration directly in you controllers is not a good idea. Rather look into strongly typed configuration settings. There are tutorials out there that can help - here's [the first link](https://andrewlock.net/how-to-use-the-ioptions-pattern-for-configuration-in-asp-net-core-rc2/) I found - but the gist is your controller will end up looking sort of like this:

```
public class CreateController : Controller
{
    public ConnectionStrings _ConnectionStrings;
    public CreateController(IOptions<ConnectionStrings> connectionStrings)
    {
        _ConnectionStrings = connectionStrings.Value;
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is null because it hasn't been set.  You need to build your configuration first which is best done in the constructor.  As others have pointed out it is not recommended to do this.

Example

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();
        }

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    private IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton(Config);            
    }
}
```